# Identifying Compiler Used for Binary File

Tags: binary-analysis

I am trying to recreate a binary file from an analysis of "strings" output. I don't recognize which compiler was used for this file. It does not seem to be shc. Does anyone recognize this output pattern from a known compiler?

```
strings *omitted*
/lib/ld-linux.so.2
libc.so.6
_IO_stdin_used
puts
setreuid
printf
getchar
system
geteuid
strcmp
__libc_start_main
__gmon_start__
GLIBC_2.0
PTRhp
QVh;
secrf
love
UWVS
t$,U
[^_]
```

I can include the rest of the output.
Edit: the scripting language is likely dash

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like strings from the first few sections of a Linux ELF32 binary created using the GCC toolchain. I can't tell you which version of GCC though.

Your question should include the output of the following commands:

- `file [name of binary]`
- `readelf -h [name of binary]`
- `readelf -SW [name of binary]`
- `objdump -dj .text [name of binary]`

`strings` output on its own is often insufficient for performing *compiler toolchain provenance*.

You also should include the full output of `strings`, because sometimes the compiler includes an identifier within the binary:

```
/lib/ld-linux.so.2
libc.so.6
_IO_stdin_used
printf
__libc_start_main
__gmon_start__
GLIBC_2.0
PTRh
[^_]
;*2$"
GCC: (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.4) 4.8.4    <------------------- 
GCC: (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) 4.8.4
.symtab
.strtab
.shstrtab
.interp
.note.ABI-tag
.note.gnu.build-id
.gnu.hash
.dynsym
.dynstr
.gnu.version
.gnu.version_r
.rel.dyn
.rel.plt
.init
.text
.fini
.rodata
.eh_frame_hdr
.eh_frame
.init_array
.fini_array
.jcr
.dynamic
.got
.got.plt
.data
.bss
.comment
crtstuff.c
__JCR_LIST__
deregister_tm_clones
register_tm_clones
__do_global_dtors_aux
completed.6600
__do_global_dtors_aux_fini_array_entry
frame_dummy
__frame_dummy_init_array_entry
trigger_sigsegv.c
__FRAME_END__
__JCR_END__
__init_array_end
_DYNAMIC
__init_array_start
_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
__libc_csu_fini
_ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
__x86.get_pc_thunk.bx
data_start
printf@@GLIBC_2.0
_edata
_fini
__data_start
__gmon_start__
__dso_handle
_IO_stdin_used
__libc_start_main@@GLIBC_2.0
__libc_csu_init
_end
_start
_fp_hw
__bss_start
main
_Jv_RegisterClasses
__TMC_END__
_ITM_registerTMCloneTable
_init
```

Comment: Thanks for the formatting guidance. I found it { strings ./check | grep "GCC"
 Output: GCC: (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 6.3.0 2017051 }

Comment: @CrippledTable You are welcome